# Merge color-related tags

Tags: discussion, tags

There are several color-related tags that don't seem to warrant separation from the [color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/color) tag: rgb, hue, contrast, and brightness. My thinking is that these concepts are rarely distinct from color when code is concerned - all of them involve storage, transformation, or manipulation of color values. Assuming it's possible, merging the tags would be a sensible move, as it would allow people to find and follow color-related questions more easily.

Comment: They will be used as sub categories on color, as there are a number of ways of representing it. A frequent requirement is to translate from one to the other so it might not be wise to get rid of them.

Comment: A good point, but I still think that the number of distinct tags makes things unwieldy; the representations are all interrelated, and every translation between representations requires two tags to be descriptive. (Thanks for the post edit - didn't even know you could add tags to the message body!)

Comment: Interesting, a [tag:rgb] tag, but no [tag:cmyk] tag...